# Não consigo ativar a função javascript

Tags: javascript, html, funções, aplicação-web, lógica

Estou tentando implementar uma função bem simples de locação de um determinado produto.

Preciso que a `id` seja lida dentro de um campo e ativada com o botão **Agendar**.

Porém  a função não é ativada quando clico no botão da página.

Estou esquecendo de algo?

Meu código `javascript`:

```js
function agendar() {

  var produto = getElementById('identificacao').value;
  var count = 0;
  var quantidade_total = 100;

  yr = prompt("Insira o ano da locação:");
  //unica data disponivel como a semana de 17/02/2020 até 21/02/2020
  mth = prompt("Insira o mes da locação:")
  day1 = prompt("Insira o dia inicial da locação:")
  day2 = prompt("Insira o dia final da locação:")
  qtde = prompt("Insira a quantidade para locação:");
  //quantidade disponivel durante esta semana:100

  if (qtde > 100 || yr != 2020 || mes != 02 || day1 < 17 || day2 > 21 || day1 > day2) {
    count = count + 1;
  } //se o count sair do zero algo está errado e não será possível alugar o que se pede.

  if (count == 0) {
    quantidade_total = quantidade_total - qtde;
    alert('Quantidade de ' + produto + ' agendados.');
  } else {
    alert('Não foi possível agendar a locação, verifica as datas e a disponibilidade');
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  Agendar produto:
  <input id="identificacao" type="text" />
  <button type="button" onclick="agendar()">Agendar</button>
</div>
```

Obrigado!

Comment: Ola @Victor, parece que esta função `getElementById('identificacao').value;` deveria ser `document.getElementById('identificacao').value;`, alem disso editei sua pergunta para apresentar melhor seu problema, você pode [reverter aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/435483/revisions)

Answer (score 2):

São dois problemas:

- Conforme o [Icaro Martins](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/3774/icaro-martins) mencionou, está faltando `document` antes do `getElementById`
- Na variável do mês, você declarou `mth` e no `if` colocou `mes`, coloquei `mes` nos 2 lugares

Abaixo o código corrigido e funcionando:

```js
function agendar() {

  var produto = document.getElementById('identificacao').value;
  var count = 0;
  var quantidade_total = 100;

  yr = prompt("Insira o ano da locação:"); 
  //unica data disponivel como a semana de 17/02/2020 até 21/02/2020
  mes = prompt("Insira o mes da locação:")
  day1 = prompt("Insira o dia inicial da locação:")
  day2 = prompt("Insira o dia final da locação:")
  qtde = prompt("Insira a quantidade para locação:"); 
  //quantidade disponivel durante esta semana:100

  if (qtde > 100 || yr != 2020 || mes != 02 || day1 < 17 || day2 > 21 || day1 > day2) {
    count = count + 1;
  } //se o count sair do zero algo está errado e não será possível alugar o que se pede.

  if (count == 0) {
    quantidade_total = quantidade_total - qtde;
    alert('Quantidade de ' + produto + ' agendados.');
  } else {
    alert('Não foi possível agendar a locação, verifica as datas e a disponibilidade');
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  Agendar produto:
  <input id="identificacao" type="text" />
  <button type="button" onclick="agendar()">Agendar</button>
</div>
```